# Running apache server, browser response says it's nginx

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

My original problem was that I can't get mod_deflate working despite ensuring it is properly installed and enabled and trying all possible .htaccess combinations. What is even more strange is that the document itself is gzipped while JS and CSS files aren't.

So this led to me another strange observation: response headers contain a line `Server: nginx`, even though I am convinced I am using Apache. How am I convinced? If I run `service apache2 stop`, the website is down. So it seems rather strange to me and I am curious why it happens and maybe it will help me to solve my original problem.

OS I am using is Debian 7, Plesk is used for configuration of Apache, and the website is running Laravel (which is of little significance I guess, but still).

I hope someone can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Run a `sudo ss -pltn` to show what process (`-p`) is listening (`-l`) on what tcp port (`-t`) without resolving names (`-n`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the same configuration as you with one of my servers. Nginx is used to manage the SSD cache after Apache.

You can change Nginx configuration with Plesk:

`Websites & Domains > domain > Web Server Settings (Additional nginx directives)`.
I use Gzip with:

```
gzip on;
gzip_comp_level 9;
gzip_disable “MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)”;
gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript text/x-js;
```

Comment: Thank you, I already figured it out, forgot to mention it here.